# Erro ao inserir no MYSQL através do PDO

Tags: pdo

Iniciei há pouco tempo na área e me deparei com esta situação.

Este meu código não está inserindo no meu MySQL.

```
 <?php
try{
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=formularioecofin', 'SECRETO', 'SECRETO');
}
catch (PDOException $e )
{
    echo 'Erro ao conectar com o MySQL: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

?>

```
  $inserir_banco = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO 'formulariodadoscadastrais' (CNPJ, RazaoSocial,  NomeFantasia, NomeResponsavel, Cpf, Telefone,CelularWhatsapp, Email) SET (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        $array_sql = array(
        $novos_campos['nCNPJ'],
        $novos_campos['nNome'],
        $novos_campos['nFantasia'],
        $novos_campos['nNomeResp'],
        $novos_campos['nCPF'],
        $novos_campos['nTelefone'],
        $novos_campos['nCelular'],
        $novos_campos['nEmail']
    );

    if($inserir_banco->execute($array_sql)){
        $respostas['erro'] = 'nao';
        $respostas['msg'] = 'Respostas cadastradas com sucesso!';
    }else{
        $respostas['erro'] = 'sim';
        $respostas['getErro'] = 'Não foi possível cadastrar as respostas. Contate seu programador!';
    }
};
```

Todas as vezes que dou o submit ele retorna "Não foi possível cadastrar as respostas. Contate seu programador!

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: Dá um var_dump($novos_campos) e vê se os valores são válidos e encaixam com os tipos de dados setados no banco. Você pode também ligar os erros pra ver melhor qual o problema. Para isso pode usar esse código no começo do script: 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *aspas simples* não são usadas para o nome de tabelas:

```
'formulariodadoscadastrais'
```

Você pode usar:

```
`formulariodadoscadastrais`
```

Ou não usar:

```
formulariodadoscadastrais
```

> Os acentos crase são usados somente quando existir palavras reservadas, espaço ou alguns tipos de caracteres não aceitos, no normal

Outra coisa o comando `INSERT INTO` não usa `SET` o correto seria `VALUES`

Deve ficar assim:

```
 INSERT INTO formulariodadoscadastrais (CNPJ, RazaoSocial, NomeFantasia, NomeResponsavel, Cpf, Telefone, CelularWhatsapp, Email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Sendo PDO você pode adicionar

```
setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Assim você poderá tratar os erros de execuções, deve ficar algo como:

```
<?php
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=formularioecofin', 'SECRETO', 'SECRETO');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $inserir_banco = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO formulariodadoscadastrais (CNPJ, RazaoSocial, NomeFantasia, NomeResponsavel, Cpf, Telefone, CelularWhatsapp, Email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    $array_sql = array(
        $novos_campos['nCNPJ'],
        $novos_campos['nNome'],
        $novos_campos['nFantasia'],
        $novos_campos['nNomeResp'],
        $novos_campos['nCPF'],
        $novos_campos['nTelefone'],
        $novos_campos['nCelular'],
        $novos_campos['nEmail']
    );

    $inserir_banco->execute($array_sql);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Erro ao conectar com o MySQL: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Perfeito Guilherme, resolvido!. Muito obrigado.